# How to call a method on program start from Java library?

Tags: java, methods

I am writing a library for Java that has several files that need to be written when the program starts (if they don't exist already).  However, most libraries do not include a 'main' method, because that is left to the program using the library.  I am wondering if there is a way to call a method when the program starts without using a main method.  I'm guessing there isn't, but if there is, I would be happy to know.  I have looked all over the web and have not found anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can use a [static initializer block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) to execute code without using a `main()` method. As soon as the class is loaded the code will be executed. For example:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: "As soon as the class is loaded..." is the important part here.  The static block will not execute unless the class is referenced somewhere else.